# XCode duplicated target fails to find image assets and compiles with linker warnings the original one doesn't

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ios7, xcode5, linker-warning

XCode 5.0
iOS 7
Cocos2d

There are many similar questions but after extensive searching, I could not find a fix.

I have a project that I am trying to make a paid version (no ads) with.
I duplicated my target and while the original target builds just fine and runs just fine, the duplicated target builds successfully however it doesn't seem to be compiling with some files even though I have checked the settings and everything seems to be OK.

It compiles with these errors:

> Original Source Codes/Kingdom Prince Source Code V.3.1.1 -
>   Risinghigh.net/A kingdom Prince Free Version/Chartboost"' ld: warning:
>   directory not found for option
>   '-L"/Users/dhbirchall/Desktop/Psychonaut ;;)/Games/Original Source
>   Codes/Kingdom Prince Source Code V.3.1.1 - Risinghigh.net/A kingdom
>   Prince Free Version/SuperKing/applovin-ios-sdk-2.0.94"' ld: warning:
>   directory not found for option
>   '-L"/Users/dhbirchall/Desktop/Psychonaut ;;)/Games/Original Source
>   Codes/Kingdom Prince Source Code V.3.1.1 - Risinghigh.net/A kingdom
>   Prince Free Version/SuperKing/Chartboost"' ld: warning: directory not
>   found for option '-F"/Users/dhbirchall/Desktop/Psychonaut
>   ;;)/Games/Original Source Codes/Kingdom Prince Source Code V.3.1.1 -
>   Risinghigh.net/A kingdom Prince Free Version/SuperKing"'

(this is source code I have purchased and the support from the seller seems to be nil and all there is is a facebook group which hasn't helped)

"SuperKing" is a folder which contains all classes and resources.

the search paths are exactly the same for both targets.

The output starts giving me these errors when I try to load the gameplay after the menu:

> 2013-10-26 11:16:01.271 SheepEscapeActive copy[370:60b]
>   /var/mobile/Applications/716E821E-69FE-4C98-AF7E-62180DB180EF/SheepEscapeActive
>   copy.app 2013-10-26 11:16:01.272 SheepEscapeActive copy[370:60b]
>   cocos2d: CCFileUtils: Warning file not found:
>   king_on_rocket_animaition_1-hd.png 2013-10-26 11:16:01.294
>   SheepEscapeActive copy[370:60b]
>   /var/mobile/Applications/716E821E-69FE-4C98-AF7E-62180DB180EF/SheepEscapeActive
>   copy.app 2013-10-26 11:16:01.296 SheepEscapeActive copy[370:60b]
>   cocos2d: CCFileUtils: Warning file not found:
>   king_on_rocket_animaition_2-hd.png

Until it crashes with:

> 2013-10-26 11:16:02.085 SheepEscapeActive copy[370:60b] cocos2d:
>   Couldn't add image:coin_yellow.png in CCTextureCache 2013-10-26
>   11:16:02.086 SheepEscapeActive copy[370:60b] *** Assertion failure in
>   -[PlayLayer addChild:], /Users/dhbirchall/Desktop/Psychonaut ;;)/Games/Original Source Codes/Kingdom Prince Source Code V.3.1.1 -
>   Risinghigh.net/A kingdom Prince Free
>   Version/SuperKing/libs/cocos2d/CCNode.m:350 (lldb)

I have two folders for graphics; one is called Art and it is in a group (yellow) folder and this contains all of the menu graphics. while the rest of the images, the gameplay images are  in a folder references (blue) folder called "levelfeatures" which contains subfolders for each image sizes (-ipad-hd to -iphone) and subfolders for each level.

As it only crashes on gameplay I think I can assume the problem is with this folder.  I checked target memberships and that is all fine.

the output shows that it can't find the assets in: /var/mobile/Applications/716E821E-69FE-4C98-AF7E-62180DB180EF/SheepEscapeActive copy.app

but the output for the original does play successfully  but still emits the same errors!:

> 2013-10-26 11:48:01.381 SheepEscape[436:60b]
>   /var/mobile/Applications/B5A5C047-79B0-4689-9255-4F2C504DB3C9/SheepEscape.app
>   2013-10-26 11:48:01.382 SheepEscape[436:60b] cocos2d: CCFileUtils:
>   Warning file not found: king_on_rocket_animaition_1-hd.png 2013-10-26
>   11:48:01.403 SheepEscape[436:60b]
>   /var/mobile/Applications/B5A5C047-79B0-4689-9255-4F2C504DB3C9/SheepEscape.app

I have tried cleaning all targets but I am completely stumped on this and would be grateful if someone with more knowledge than me could help.

Thanks for any responses and if any more information is needed to help solve I will post it but I don't know what other information is relevant to this problem.

Thank you,

David

Comment: Compare both target's Build Settings and Build Phases and re-apply any difference (besides the obvious, like different project/target names) to the copied project.